# Can I display Interstitial Ad before transiting to page containing YouTube player and other stuff?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a Recipes Android app with the following flow:

```
a. User searches for a recipe or selects a playlist
b. The videos corresponding to search word or the videos of the playlist are displayed using YouTube API.
c. On selecting the video the user is displayed a page containing:
   1. YouTube player
   2. Buttons to share and save recipe
   3. Recipe Ingredients & Details
   4. Functionality to create shopping list based on ingredients
   5. Suggested videos loaded using YouTube API
```

**As per YouTube Api Terms of Service**, can I display Interstitial Ad before loading the video page which contains the YouTube Player and other items mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [creating an interstitial ad](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) using AdMob with Firebase.
You should be aware that according to YouTube's Terms of Service, it's forbidden to do so on top of any data served using their API, as quoted [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies):

> You and your API Clients must not, and must not encourage, enable, or require others to: [...]
>
> c. sell advertising, sponsorships, or promotions that are placed on or within YouTube audiovisual content or the YouTube player without YouTube's prior written approval; or
>
> d. sell advertising, sponsorships, or promotions on any page or screen that contains YouTube API Data unless other data, content, or material not obtained from YouTube appears on the same page and offers enough independent value to justify such sales if the YouTube API Data were removed.

Comment: The issue is whether as per YouTube Api TOS can I add an interstitial ad. I know how to add the Interstitial ad the issue is regarding compliance with YouTube Api TOS

Comment: Seems that the answer to this question is no. I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: Is there any way to monetize my app

Comment: You could show your ads upon exiting the screen rather than entering, or according to (d), if the screen offers enough independent content apart from the YouTube data, you can show a small ad inside that screen